# Kafka disk space gets full

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a Kafka service with 1000GB disk and this running parameter:

```
log.retention.bytes=350000000000
```

However, the usage of disk space reaches 90% (900GB). Since that parameter is running, the disk size should not exceeds 326GB. Why could this happen?

Other properties:

```
log.index.interval.bytes=4000
log.segment.bytes=250000000
log.index.size.max.bytes=10485760
log.retention.ms=168
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while the [official documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs) isnt very clear:

> The maximum size of the log before deleting it

the [confluent documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/topic-configs.html) on topic configs (which should really be considered the official documentation anyway) has a better one (under retention.bytes):

> This configuration controls the maximum size a partition (which consists of log segments) can grow to before we will discard old log segments to free up space if we are using the "delete" retention policy. By default there is no size limit only a time limit. Since this limit is enforced at the partition level, multiply it by the number of partitions to compute the topic retention in bytes.

in short, this config isnt even per topic. **its per partition**. im not aware of a kafka config that acts as a broker-wide size limit.

if youre trying to balance data load across multiple brokers in a cluster perhaps you should look at [cruise control](https://github.com/linkedin/cruise-control)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @radai. One more question.. Assume there are 3 topics in this broker and each has 3 partitiions. So `log.retention.bytes=350000000000` means the total size can reach `326GB*9=2925GB` ?